# Showing function from interval to $\mathbb{N}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of measurable functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$.

 Let $G(x)=card (\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid f_n(x)=0\})$ and assume $G(x)$ is finite for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.

 I need to show that $G$ is measurable.

 So $G(x)$ gives the number of functions from $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which take the value $0$ at $x$. How can I prove that the inverse image of $G$ of every element in the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$? In particualar, I am not sure what the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-algebra is not on $\Bbb N$, but on the domain of $G$, which is $[0,1]$. And it's, of course, Lebesgue's $\sigma$-algebra (though it could really be any $\sigma$-algebra making all the $f_n$-s measurable).

The goal is to show that $G^{-1}[\alpha,\infty)$ is measurable for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

If $\alpha\le0$, that set is obviously the whole domain $[0,1]$. For $\alpha>0$, notice that $x\in G^{-1}\left[\alpha,\infty\right)$ if and only if there is $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $\operatorname{card}S=\left\lceil \alpha\right\rceil$ and $x\in f_s^{-1}(0)$ for all $s\in S$. Therefore, call $\mathcal P_n(\Bbb N)=\{S\subseteq \Bbb N\,:\, \operatorname{card}S=n\}$, and we see that $$G^{-1}[\alpha,\infty)=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal P_{\left\lceil\alpha\right\rceil}(\Bbb N)}\bigcap_{s\in S}f_s^{-1}(0)$$

which is measurable because $\mathcal P_{\left\lceil\alpha\right\rceil}(\Bbb N)$ is countable, each $S$ is finite (hence countable) and all the $f_s^{-1}(0)$ are measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\phi_n(x) = 1_{ \{ 0 \} } (f_n(x))$ is measurable since $f_n$ is measurable. ($1_{ \{ 0 \} }$ is the characteristic function of the set $\{0\}$.)

Hence $G = \sum_n \phi_n$ is measurable. This holds whether or not $G$ is finite.